# Equivalent definitions of a lattice (discrete subgroup)

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group. A discrete subgroup $\Gamma\le G$ is called lattice, if $G/\Gamma$ admits a non-trivial finite invariant Radon measure (or regular Borel measure, if you wish). On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(discrete_subgroup)) it is stated that this definition is equivalent to $\Gamma$ having a fundamental domain of finite volume, i.e. some measurable $V\subseteq G$ such that $V\Gamma=G$ and $V\gamma_1\cap V\gamma_2=\emptyset$ for $\gamma_1\ne\gamma_2$ and $m(V)<\infty$, where $m$ is the Haar measure on G.

The statement that every lattice admits a measurable fundamental domain is somewhat standard in the literature, however I only ever saw it being proven for Abelian groups or groups with some other extra assumption such as $\sigma$-compactness.

How do I prove that every lattice on a locally compact Hausdorff group admits a fundamental domain?

Comment: Fundamental domain of finite volume!

Comment: @MoisheKohan Correct, I forgot to write. You don't happen to know a reference, do you?

Comment: Yes, but I need to check.

Comment: I mean  I think I saw it in a particular book, but I do not have an immediate access to it right now.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Do you remember the name of the book?

Comment: It is in Margulis "Discrete subgroups of semisimple Lie groups". Margulis, however, does not give a proof but refers to Bourbaki's "Integration."

Comment: @MoisheKohan Funnily enough, I already found this book and I even checked Bourbaki. Margulis claims that the assertion follows from an exercise in Bourbaki Integration Ch. 7, however he only states it for $\sigma$-compact groups and despite that, I cannot prove the exercise.

Comment: Do you need it in full generality or sigma-compact groups would suffice?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Technically, it would suffice. However, there has to be a proof for the fully general case somewhere, right?

Comment: A detailed proof of a similar fact is given in Siegel's article (Discontinuous groups, Annals of Mathematics vol. 44, no. 4) in Lemma 1 and Lemma 2. But it requires a locally compact group to satisfy the second axiom of countability.